# Exit a while loop with one specific key stroke in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to exit a while loop with this one specific character key input `|`.
The only way I figured out how is to transform the `int` user input in `char`. For some reason, when I input the `|` character when the program is running, I only receive: `Press any key to continue...`. My final goal (as I hope is visible from my code) is for the program to actually list all inputs in my vector and then terminate.

I am new to C++ and very lost on this point. If anyone could point me in the right direction I will be very appreciative.

I am running a Windows 8 Entreprise machine.

**About the program**

This is a simple program that takes user input of integers, adds them to a vector and compares the last two to see which one is bigger, smaller etc.

**Full code is here**

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

// conversion of units to meters

double funconvert(double x, string unit)
{
    const double cm_m = 1.0 / 100.0, in_cm = 2.54, ft_in = 12;
    if (unit == "m")
        return x;
    else if (unit == "cm")
        return x = x * cm_m;
    else if (unit == "in")
        return x = x * in_cm * cm_m;
    else if (unit == "ft")
        return x = x * ft_in * in_cm * cm_m;
    else
        cout << "Unknown unit value.\n";
}

// printing the large and the small variables
void printresult(double smallest, double largest)
{
    cout << "the smaller value is: " << smallest << "\n";
    cout << "the larger value is: " << largest << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    vector<double>numbers;
    double a, b, smallest, largest;
    char the_stop;
    string unit;
    cout << "Please enter an intiger followed by a measurment unit [e.g 10cm]:";

    // Take input
    while (cin >> a)
    {
        char the_stop = a;
        cin >> unit;
        cout << the_stop;
        // check if this is the first number entered
        if (numbers.size() == 0)
        {
            a = funconvert(a, unit);
            b = a;
            numbers.push_back(a);
            numbers.push_back(b);
        }
        else if (the_stop == '|')
        {
            // This is not working for some reason... ERROR
            sort(numbers);
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
                cout << numbers[i];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //assign a and b to the last two numbers in a vector
            a = funconvert(a, unit);
            numbers.push_back(a);
            a = numbers[(numbers.size() - 1)];
            b = numbers[(numbers.size() - 2)];
            // numbers.erase(numbers.begin()); // enable if desire to keep the vector empty
        }

        // find out which variable is larger and smaller
        if (a > b && (a/b-1) >= 0.01)
        {
            smallest = b;
            largest = a;
            printresult(smallest, largest);
        }
        else if (a < b && (b / a - 1) >= 0.01)
        {
            smallest = a;
            largest = b;
            printresult(smallest, largest);
        }
        else if ((a / b - 1) < 0.01 && (a / b - 1) != 0.00 || (b / a - 1) < 0.01 && (a / b - 1) != 0.00)
        {
            cout << "the nubers are almost equal\n";
        }
        else
            cout << a << " equals " << b << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Code UPDATED**

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

// conversion of units to meters

double funconvert(double x, string unit)
{
    const double cm_m = 1.0 / 100.0, in_cm = 2.54, ft_in = 12;
    if (unit == "m")
        return x;
    else if (unit == "cm")
        return x = x * cm_m;
    else if (unit == "in")
        return x = x * in_cm * cm_m;
    else if (unit == "ft")
        return x = x * ft_in * in_cm * cm_m;
    else
        cout << "Unknown unit value.\n";
}

// printing the large and the small variables
void printresult(double smallest, double largest)
{
    cout << "the smaller value is: " << smallest << "\n";
    cout << "the larger value is: " << largest << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    vector<double>numbers;
    double a, b, smallest, largest;
    char the_stop;
    string unit;
    cout << "Please enter an intiger:";

    // Take input
    while (cin >> a)
    {

        // check if the | character is pressed
        char the_stop = a;
        if (the_stop == '|')
        {
            cout << "start";
            sort(numbers);
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
                cout << numbers[i];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "And now the unit value:";
            cin >> unit;
        }

        // check if this is the first number entered
        if (numbers.size() == 0)
        {
            a = funconvert(a, unit);
            b = a;
            numbers.push_back(a);
            numbers.push_back(b);
        }
        else
        {
            //assign a and b to the last two numbers in a vector
            a = funconvert(a, unit);
            numbers.push_back(a);
            a = numbers[(numbers.size() - 1)];
            b = numbers[(numbers.size() - 2)];
            // numbers.erase(numbers.begin()); // enable if desire to keep the vector empty
        }

        // find out which variable is larger and smaller
        if (a > b && (a/b-1) >= 0.01)
        {
            smallest = b;
            largest = a;
            printresult(smallest, largest);
        }
        else if (a < b && (b / a - 1) >= 0.01)
        {
            smallest = a;
            largest = b;
            printresult(smallest, largest);
        }
        else if ((a / b - 1) < 0.01 && (a / b - 1) != 0.00 || (b / a - 1) < 0.01 && (a / b - 1) != 0.00)
        {
            cout << "the nubers are almost equal\n";
        }
        else
            cout << a << " equals " << b << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try flushing the stream? The output probably isn't long enough, so the text is probably just sitting in the buffer waiting to be flushed. Also, you'll probably want it to insert a space after `number[i] `, or it will all run together

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the feedback. If you want, check my last code (in the Code updated section below the original one). I moved things around a bit so that it does not just sit there, however I cannot figure out why, but I still get the same response from my cmnd line
I did not understand whay you meant by the space bit by the way.

Comment: @Newskooler: I did not realize this before, but the type of `a` is `double`. What you should probably do instead is read an entire line with `std::getline`, and then check the first character against `|`. Otherwise, assume you received a value. Alternatively, make `a` an `int`, and then when you want to do your conversion, create a `double` from the int.